# increase hokuyo URG-04LX-01 scan Frequency

Tags: lidar, scan, frequency, hokuyo, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do i increase hokuyo URG-04LX-01 to scan at a higher Frequency.
current it is 10Hz. i have add  param name="Skip" value = "1"/ to my launch file, but a i increase the Value the Frequency Drop

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173478/increase-hokuyo-urg-04lx-01-scan-frequency/) by [vinod9910](https://answers.ros.org/users/18770/vinod9910/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't increase it beyond 10Hz, that is the maximum scanning rate of the URG-04 according to the specs. By increasing the "skip" beyond 0, you are dropping data so your scanning frequency will be reduced (skip=1  => 5Hz).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vinod9910](https://answers.ros.org/users/18770/vinod9910/) on 2014-06-12**:
Thank You.